# AADB2C90238: The provided token does not contain a valid issuer. Please provide another token and try again

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

I am using ADB2C and added AAD as identity provider for Home realm discovery. HRD is working as expected and it redirect user to AAD(https://login.microsoftonline.com) basis on domain for authentication and after successful authentication it redirect to jwt.ms with "AADB2C90238: The provided token does not contain a valid issuer. Please provide another token and try again." error code.
Below is my Technical profile and User journey.

```
      <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-OIDC">
                    <DisplayName>Login with AAD (OIDC)</DisplayName>
                    <Description>Login with AAD (OIDC)</Description>
                    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
                    <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/CloudSolution2022.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/ffc9d30c-a7e7-486d-bbcd-66d88af6f4c9/</Item>
                        <Item Key="client_id">8d102d89-864e-417e-912d-3e3441cc4bf5</Item>
                        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">8d102d89-864e-417e-912d-3e3441cc4bf5</Item>
                        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
                        <Item Key="resource">https://graph.windows.net</Item>
                        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
                        <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
                        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
                        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                        <Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>
                        <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">cloud-solutions.co.in</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_aadSecretFederation" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <!--Demo: pass the login_hint to Azure AD home realm discovery page-->
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="CloudSolution" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AADOIDCIDP" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
                    <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
```

User Journey

```
   <UserJourney Id="SignIn">

            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="SigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Signin-Email" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="ParseDomainHintLogic" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="HRDLogic" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- If the domain_hint did not match any known domain, then redirect to a default local account sign in-->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <!-- dont run this step if the domain was known, or we have an objectid (local account sign in)-->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>objectId</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- If the domain matched any known domain, then this step will have a single IdP
                    enabled due to each known IdP TP having an enablement flag via identityProviders claim -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADOIDC" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>objectId</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADOIDC" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-OIDC" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- Still dont have objectId (social idp user that doesnt yet exist) - write the account -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>objectId</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>isKnownCustomer</Value>
                            <Value>True</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
            <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>
```

I traced these requests and able to get token with all values as below.

[image]

Let me know if any additional information needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380662/azure-b2c-the-provided-token-does-not-contain-a-valid-issuer

Comment: Thanks rbrayb, issue mentioned in above provided link is related to some duplicate key. I verified it but its not the case with me..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing below item from metadata.

```
<Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/ffc9d30c-a7e7-486d-bbcd-66d88af6f4c9/</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue, but I am trying to support multi-tenant Microsoft accounts. I am using Azure AD B2C with the `organizations` metadata link in order to support login from any corp microsoft account. The login is successful, but the error is reported back that the issuer does not match. I have tried this in user flows and custom policy, but it doesn't work. I would prefer to make this work with user flows as I don't find custom policies to easy to use or understand.

```
AADB2C90238: The provided token does not contain a valid issuer. Please provide another token and try again.
```

Metadata Link:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

#### Option 1: User Flow

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to Azure b2c > Identity Provider
- Create New Identity Providers > provide the details including the metadata url provided above. [New Identity Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABnPi.png)
- Assign the identity provider to a signin and signup user flow
- Run the user flow with redirect url to be `https://jwt.ms/`
- Login with you microsoft corp account.
- Redirect to `jwt.ms` with error shown above.

#### Option 2: Custom Policy

Only the claim provider section has been shown here.

```xml
    <!-- Social User Login -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Microsoft</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="UserAccount-Micrsoft">
          <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID --> 
            <Item Key="client_id">client_id</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MicrosoftSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInEmail" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInEmail" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing below item from metadata.

```
<Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/ffc9d30c-a7e7-486d-bbcd-66d88af6f4c9/</Item>
```

After to do this, I receive the error:

```
AADB2C: 'B2C_1A_signin_with_microsoft_social' policy in 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' specifies the subject claim 'sub' which is missing in the claims collection.
```

Anyone saw this message?

Comment: It means the attribute named sub is missing in the token. you can either include an attribute sub in the token or change it to id attribute in b2c policy